# iOS App unable to download from AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

iOS App unable to download from AppStore. Deployment target is set to iOS 7 or later. Unable to install in iOS 7 & iOS 8, but successfully installing on iOS9.

App Uploaded from Xcode 7 with deployment target iOS7. base

[image]

[image]

Comment: Contact Apple, there seems to be an issue with the file on their servers.

Comment: Contact Apple by sending email .

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue just as the screenshot you post about 5 days ago,

**My app can be download about 2 days after the new version is released,which means the issue continues only 2 days**

I also send Apple team an email,but when they reply the issue is gone.(They reply after **3 days**)

**So what you can do**

1. Since app is successfully released,you can just contact the Apple
   team,in the bottom of itunes connect webpage,select **contact us** 
   to send email.
2. Submit a new version,then **request expedited review**

Comment: Why you think this is not an answer? I shared my experience and tell him that the only way is send apple an email. This is not an answer?